# Two XML files. Roughly same number of lines. One is twice the size of the other. How?

Tags: xml, vb.net, vba, file-io, filesize

I have been generating an XML sitemap using Access and VBA. I asked our developers to implement a server side solution so that it can be ran every night without me having to remember to do it.

I generate the file by writing text to a file. Very simple. My file is around 1800KB.

The developer's solution writes text to a file (use the XmlWriter VB class). His file is around 900KB.

When he first showed me this I assumed he was missing a lot of data from the sitemap. When I checked the number of lines in each there are only 38 lines difference (out of around 22,500 lines of text).

How can this be?

Not sure if this is the correct stackexchange site to post this on but I don't of a more appropriate one.

### Edit

Here is an example of the file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.bodykind.com/index.aspx</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.bodykind.com/category/3-Supplements.aspx</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.bodykind.com/category/4-Wellbeing.aspx</loc>
    </url>
    ...
```

Both the files are almost exactly the same but the <url> are in a different order and one has about 36 more lines than the other.

## Edit 2

I have just checked the document properties. It seems the code set of the 900KB file is UTF-8 but the codeset of the 1800KB file is Unicode. I am assuming this is why there is such a big difference?

## Edit 3

Since it is on the verge of being closed, here is the code for both

### My VBA

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    pIndent = True
    Set objADO = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objADO.Type = 2
    objADO.Charset = "utf-8"
    objADO.LineSeparator = 10
    objADO.Open
    objADO.WriteText "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>", 1
End Sub

... some code which writes the text to the file

Public Sub SaveToFile(ByVal PATH As String)
    ' Skip the BOM
    objADO.Position = 3

    Dim BinaryStream As Object
    Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.stream")
    BinaryStream.Type = 1
    BinaryStream.Mode = adModeReadWrite
    BinaryStream.Open

    'Strips BOM (first 3 bytes)
    objADO.CopyTo BinaryStream
    objADO.flush
    objADO.Close

    BinaryStream.SaveToFile PATH, 2
    BinaryStream.flush
    BinaryStream.Close

    Set BinaryStream = Nothing
    Set objADO = Nothing
End Sub
```

### The developers solution

```
Using writer As New XmlTextWriter(Server.MapPath(filename), Encoding.UTF8)
    writer.WriteStartDocument()
    writer.WriteStartElement("urlset")
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9")
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented

    writer.WriteStartElement("url")
    writer.WriteElementString("loc", domain + "/index.aspx")
    writer.WriteEndElement()

    writer.WriteStartElement("url")
    writer.WriteElementString("loc", domain + "/aboutus.aspx")
    writer.WriteEndElement()

    ... and so on....
```

Comment: "Guess why this code (that I've not shown you) produces different output than this code (that I've not shown you)? I'm not going to show you the output either" - no thanks.

Comment: This questions has received a close vote because it is deemed as off topic. I am happy to move it to a more appropriate stackexchange if someone points one out to me. I feel it is on-topic because two developers are programmatically creating an almost identical text file yet one is twice the size. How is that possible?

Comment: maybe you use spaces instead of tab for indentation?

Comment: @thanks tezzo and Damien_The_Unbeliever, these are the kind of answers I am looking for. I have used tabs (mine is 1800KB) he has used spaces so I thought that would make mine smaller! Mine should be UTF8. Which would produce the smaller file? UTF-8 or 16 ( I assume 16)

Comment: can you take a part of your generated xml file and put it in notepad++ and then compare it with the xml files generated with the VB XmlWriter and select the show all characters options. There may be difference in the newline and space characters.

Comment: @BogdanBanciu when I do that the only difference I can see are that I use tabs, he has used spaces.

Comment: To figure this out we would need either 1) the actual files (not a cut and paste of some of the text), or, 2) the code that produces both files. Failing that, this is just a request for guesses with no real possibility of truly figuring it out (i.e., a fishing expedition).  I am voting to close on that basis.

Comment: @MrMisterMan i think access and other office applications add an invisible header to the file when it writes xml, or html or other formats... but i could be wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's twice the size, then one is UTF-8 (the smaller one) and one is UTF-16 (the bigger one). In UTF-16, every ASCII character takes twice as much space as in UTF-8.

(And Unicode means (in Windows) UTF-16).

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be the reason.